# runOnUiThread() doesn't call my Runnable's run()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I try to use runOnUiThread() method, but for some reason the code in my run() is never called.

As a result my program come to a deadlock (The CountDownLatch awaits forever).

Can someone tell why my run() method isn't called on the UI thread?

```
private final CountDownLatch m_latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

m_mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        // Here I have a breakpoint (never stops here)

        // Do somethings that has to be done on the main thread

        m_latch.countDown(); 
    }           
});

try {
    // Wait for m_bundle to get set         
    m_latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Comment: maybe you are calling the method from UI thread, use a post() or postDelayed()

Comment: Why? If it's the UI thread, let it call run() immediately - what's the problem with that?

Comment: @user1028741 the UI thread is blocked by `m_latch.await()` before it can run the Runnable. It doesn't make sense to use thread-synchronizing mechanisms (as a CountDownLatch) with one single thread only!

Comment: @isnot2bad, I don't understand what you mean - there are 2 threads (my worker thread, and the main-ui-thread). Why doesn't the runnable run before the m_latch.await()???

Comment: @user1028741, runOnUiThread does not run the Runnable immediately, but put it on a queue.

Comment: Of course, but isn't the UI-thread supposed to pull it from this queue in it's own context??